# Accessing API with Apps Scripts, but IP restricted from US region

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to access the Binance API from a Google Sheet using a Apps Script function. Unfortunately api.binance.com is restricted from the US and responds with a 451 and api.binance.us does not have the data I require.

Is it possible make the Sheet/script execute the request from a different region?

Alternatively, is there a way to proxy the request via another region? Web proxies don't seem to offer a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking for an alternative API you can use before you attempt this. You can use proxies (free proxies are not recommended as they are known for reading your traffic) in the region you want (outside of the US in your case) which will only help if the binance API uses your IP address to find your region. If they somehow accept the region as a header or use your timezone to determine your region, you will have to spoof those values.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'm going with is using a market data service like Coin Market Cap or CoinGecko.